Почему в modx изменился шаблон страницы после перевода его в статичный режим?
В MODX Revolution 2.8.6-pl переключил шаблон главной страницы в статичный режим, что бы можно было редактировать его в файле. После этого код шаблона странным образом изменился. Такое ощущение что это какой то старый шаблон. Я посмотрел файл шаблона из бэкапа. Там тот же код ("новый"). Как будто при переключении в статичный режим код из файла перезаписал код который был в базе. Я переключил режим шаблона обратно на динамический, но это не помогло. Почему так произошло?

Вероятно действительно в указанном имени нового шаблона в файле уже что-то было сохранено, при переключении MODX это подхватил и записал вместо вашего кода шаблона.
Подбирайте уникальные имена на будущее :)
Вам нужно восстановить данные или просто сам механизм подмены интересен? Если первое - бекап поможет, или VersionX(если вдруг используется).

я потестил, действительно файл перезаписывает то что было в базе. я боялся что если восстановить базу, то все что я деле придется делать снова. но вроде все нормально.
